# SwiftUI some times is not updating @EnvironmentObject

Tags: swift, swiftui

In this example I am trying save state in `@EnvironmentObject` and pass it to `DepthButtonView`, but my issue is that some times it misses `settings.tradeChartType` update in `DepthButtonView`. is it bug or I am doing something wrong?

P.S.
I know `@State` Property, just I need this kind of setup in my project

Any recommendations would be appreciated

```
struct BodyView: View {
    
    var hideAction: () -> Void
    var fullScreenAction: () -> Void
    var chartTypeAction: (TradeChartView.ChartType) -> Void
    
    @EnvironmentObject var settings: AppSettings
    
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            Button(action: {
                
                if settings.tradeChartType == .trading {
                    settings.tradeChartType = .depth
                    
                } else {
                    settings.tradeChartType = .trading
                    
                }
                
                chartTypeAction(settings.tradeChartType)
            }, label: {
                DepthButtonView(tradeChartType: $settings.tradeChartType)
            })
            Spacer()
            Button(action: {
                fullScreenAction()
            }, label: {
                Image("HeaderTradeChartZoom")
            })
            if !settings.tradeChertFullScreen {
                Button(action: {
                    hideAction()
                }, label: {
                    Image("HeaderTradeChartHide")
                })
            }
        }
    }
    struct DepthButtonView: View {
        @Binding var tradeChartType: TradeChartView.ChartType
        
        var body: some View {
            Group {
                Text(LocalString(tradeChartType == .trading ? "cis.retail.ios.header.depth.button" : "cis.retail.ios.header.trading.button"))
                    .customFont(name: .ubuntuMedium, size: 16)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.primaryBlue).fixedSize()
                Image("HeaderLeftBlueArrow")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a reason to have Binding here, so try to use directly, like

```
DepthButtonView(tradeChartType: settings.tradeChartType)
```

and

```
struct DepthButtonView: View {
    var tradeChartType: TradeChartView.ChartType
    
    var body: some View {
        // .. other code
```

Note: I assume `tradeChartType` is `@Published` in `AppSettings`